# How to update title in section header

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableView where the title in the header for each section displays a date for the content in the current section -- except when the date is today it displays *Today* and if the date was yesterday, it displays *Yesterday*.

As these titles are non-static, they change when a new day comes. In that case, I have to scroll down and up again, to get my title in the header updated.

What is the best approach for getting this header updated after midnight?

Comment: As iDifferent said, just reload the data of your tableView but are you planning on checking every minutes if it is tomorrow to reload the data ?

Comment: I'm not sure, when I should check for this. Checking every minute is not a good idea. Anyone having any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO I don't think this is good practice to automatically refresh the data after midnight or even to refresh data every now and again. You should just let the user do it whenever he wants and also reload data when the app is launched or when the main window reappears.

If you really need this feature maybe, every time the app is launched, you could calculate the time left until midnight and you use a `NSTimer` to fire the reload method

```
timerNoTwo = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:secondsUntilMidnight target:self selector:@selector(refreshTableView) userInfo:nil NO];
```

And then

```
-(void)refreshTableView{ [tableView reloadData]; }
```

Comment: The true problem comes, when the app is going to background and then opening the next day. Then the app is just continuing from last day, and the headers are from yesterday. Maybe I should store a date in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` and check this date in `applicationDidBecomeActive` to check if it is a new day?

Comment: Why don't you just refresh the tableview in the applicationDidBecomeActive. It doesn't matter if the app entered background a week ago. Just refresh anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Probably try `[tableView reloadData];` to refresh the table after midnight.